# Cant pass large uint in react.js (2**256-1) into solidity approve function

Tags: solidity, erc-20, javascript, react, erc-20-approve

I am trying to call a simple approve() to allow my contract to spend my tokens.
Trying to make the amount argument = (2**256 - 1) however I am getting the below error message every time.

Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid number value (arg="amount", coderType="uint256", value="1.157920892373162e+77")
▶ 11 stack frames were collapsed.

I have tried putting the number in hex, I have tried toString() also, but I get the same error every time.

The below code is called when a button in my front-end is pressed.

```
approveSpend = async() => {
    const maxSpend = (2**256-1);
    const forwardAuctionAddress = ForwardAuction.networks[this.networkId].address;
    await this.tokenInstance.methods.approve(forwardAuctionAddress, maxSpend.toString()).send({from: this.accounts[0]});
    
  }
```

Can anyone please help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can't handle big numbers natively. That's where various `BigNumber` libraries come to play.

To be consistent, it's best to always use `BigNumber` when dealing with integers in web3 projects. There are tons of different libraries out there, but I recommend using the one which your web3 library uses under the hood - you'll probably get utils for it directly from your web3 library.

Comment: Hi, would you please be able to help me with how to do that? I have tried so many different things, different packages, everything and I just cant get it to work.

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to have

const maxInt = new BN(2^256 - 1);

You need to make each number a new BN and perform the arithemetic to make it work. Also the numbers have to be in quotations I think.

const maxInt= new BN("2").pow(new BN("256").sub(new BN("1"))); // Will pass into solidity as uint 2**256 - 1

Comment: Please check https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#bn

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to have

```
const maxInt = new BN(2^256 - 1);
```

You need to make each number a new BN and perform the arithemetic to make it work. Also the numbers have to be in quotations I think.

```
const maxInt= new BN("2").pow(new BN("256")).sub(new BN("1")); // Will pass into solidity as uint 2**256 - 1
```

////////////